# Ender 3 V2 error message

Tags: creality-ender-3, extruder, printer-building

I bought an Ender 3 V2 printer and printed successfully with PLA and PLA+. Ender 3 V2 is rated at <= 250 °C but when I set temperature above 200 °C to print to PLA+, I get an error message "Nozzle is too lowperature" and the printer freezes (the term lowperature is actual and not a typo error).

I tried to raise the temperature gradually. I started at 200 °C and have gone to 205 °C and a little bit more. I started printing and I might get this message again or might not. Also, the temperature seems to change or lower while printing. It is not stable.

Any suggestions as to what causes this unstable behavior?

---

Following the above behavior, I was able to raise the temperature to 213 °C and I was printing for 10 minutes or so, then I got the message "thermal runaway".

---

I managed to capture the event [here](https://youtu.be/oo0f237iTVo)

Comment: A quick Google search shows some Reddit posts talking about a bad thermistor. You may need to contact either Creality or the store you purchased the printer from.

Comment: @agarza That sounds as an answer! 

Comment: Can you remove the fan cover on the print head, and show what it looks like ?  I'm expecting a sharp kink in the thermister wiring which is messing up its readings.  Or it might be faulty internally.

Comment: @Criggie I removed the fan cover but there is nothing out of order there. The fan works ok and the cables are firmly screwed on the head.

Comment: @agarza I will contact the store

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a bad thermistor. Try replacing the head thermistor, see if this fixes it.

As for the strange error message, it looks like the word Temperature is being drawn on the wrong line, and then "is too low" writes over it.

See the way the word lines up below:

```
nozzle temperature
is too lowperature
```

Comment: Strange message, see message on display [here](https://i.redd.it/i7glbtk57gs51.jpg).

Comment: If the newline character were missing, it would look more like "nozzle temperatureis too low" On these types of LCD screens, text is drawn progressively. Characters are grouped into words and are drawn in order. If the Y position of the word "temperature" were to be shifted down by one line (problem in the firmware), it would be drawn first, and then "is too low" would be drawn over it, regardless of word position.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after the supplier replaced the motherboard.
However after that I had to try various versions of firmware as different ones had different behavior to the printer.
If you face a similar situation be aware of the cabling and connections when changing the motherboard. You may have to do the plugins twice to be sure that they are correctly attached.